# iOS people picker get contact emails in array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I'm trying to get emails from a contact in my people picker (iOS), but I'm encountering a little problem (since Swift 2.0, before it was working nice) : I want to get that emails in a string array, but when I print it, it looks like this :

`["(\n    \"myEmail1.com\",\n    \"myEmail2.com\",\n    \"myEmail3\"\n)"]`

Here is my code :

```
if ((ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonEmailProperty)) != nil) {
        let email: ABMultiValueRef = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonEmailProperty).takeRetainedValue() as ABMultiValueRef
        self.contactSelectedEmails = [String(ABMultiValueCopyArrayOfAllValues(email).takeUnretainedValue())]
        print(self.contactSelectedEmails)
        prefs.setObject(self.contactSelectedEmails, forKey: self.contactSelectedName.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "").lowercaseString + "_emails")
}
```

When I print `self.contactSelectedEmails[0]`, I can get my array but I can't store it in the var.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the CNContact stuff instead of the AB framework?

I recently converted all of my code to use CNContact and I haven't had any issues in Swift 2.

For reference, below is some code that grabs an email address and saves it into core data, but you could just as easily put it in an array. It wasn't as painful as I thought it'd be to convert to the CNContact framework, and it actually made my code a bit simpler.

```
func presentPicker() {
    let contactPicker = CNContactPickerViewController()
    contactPicker.delegate = self
    contactPicker.displayedPropertyKeys = [CNContactEmailAddressesKey]
    print("ContactPicker called")
    self.presentViewController(contactPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
func contactPicker(picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelectContactProperty contactProperty: CNContactProperty) {
    let contact = contactProperty.contact
    let name = "\(contact.givenName) \(contact.familyName)"
    let email = contactProperty.value

    let aFetchedRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Recipients")

    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name == %@", contact)
    aFetchedRequest.predicate = predicate
    let recordCheck = managedObjectContext!.countForFetchRequest(aFetchedRequest, error: nil)

    if recordCheck > 0 {
        //if person is in MOC
        let thePerson = (try! managedObjectContext!.executeFetchRequest(aFetchedRequest)) as! [Recipients]
        thePerson[0].emailRecipient = "\(email!)"
        thePerson[0].name = name

        print("does exist name \(thePerson[0].name)")

    } else {
        //if person isn't in MOC
        let newRecipient = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Recipients", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!) as! Recipients


        newRecipient.emailRecipient = "\(email!)"
        newRecipient.name = name
        newRecipient.uniqueIdentifier = NSUUID().UUIDString
        print("didn't exist name: \(String(name))")
    }
    var error : NSError? = nil
    do {
        try managedObjectContext!.save()
    } catch let error1 as NSError {
        error = error1
        NSLog("Unresolved error \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
        abort()
    }

    do {
        try managedObjectContext!.save()
    } catch _ {
    }
    getFetchResultsController()
    theTableView.reloadData()
    print("Stored number: = \(email!)")

}
```